# bulkCreate junction table data in sequelize for establishing many-to-many association

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models - User and Flat. They have a many-to-many association

```
Flat.belongsToMany(User, { through: FlatMember });
User.belongsToMany(Flat, { through: FlatMember });
```

Now I have an array of objects storing the data of which user is associated to which Flat

```
flatMemberArray = [{userId: 1, flatId: 'A1'}, 
                   {userId: 2, flatId: 'A1'}, 
                   {userId: 2, flatId: 'A2'}];
```

How do I do a bulkCreate and insert this flatMemberArray into the junction FlatMember Model.

I went through the documentation and found no help. There is a single record creation possible with

`userInstance.setFlats(flatIds); //array of flatIds associated to the user instance`

But then I would have to run a for loop for each user to do this insertion. There surely must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`FlatMember.bulkCreate([arrayOfDataObjects])`

does work. I am just a ridiculous human being who made an error in creating the Data Objects which had the foreign key id assigned as something that did not exist as a Primary Key in the User model. The catched error message talked about missing parameters, which I misconstrued. This is corrected now.